# Provide access to Oracle database through a gateway

Tags: networking, apache-2.4, oracle, gateway

I describe the problem as :
We have multiple developers on a LAN, having development database (ORACLE) on the same LAN.

There is a production database out of the LAN, but a single computer on this LAN has access to it through a VPN.

Is there any way for me to configure the gateway, so developers can access the remote production database on their machines?

I shall mention that there is an Apache HTTPD on the gateway machine, which proxies production web applications for developers team.

Comment: Have you worked with your network team on this? Or whomever set up the VPN?

Comment: Well the VPN is set by creating a simple VPN connection on the Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Your VPN connection is set up using standard workstation VPN software, which is not suitable for providing infrastructure VPN service. You will need to work with your network team to provide a network-level VPN to your Oracle instance.